# Json data cannot be displayed in div section using Ajax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I created a json of this format of a external php file:

```
[
{
    "title": "Welcome!",
    "description": "The world has changed dramatically..",
    "image": "img/strawberry-wallpaper.jpg"
}
]
```

I am using this to display data to a specific div section but I have no results:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
 url: 'json.php',
 type: 'post',
 data: { get_param: 'value' },
 contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data){
     var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if(obj.success){
            $.each(obj, function (index, item) { 
                    if ('success'!= index){
             $('#output').append("<div class='col-md-6' ><img class='img-rounded' src="+item.image+"alt='MyImage' width='550px' height='240px'></div><div class='col-md-6'><h3>"+item.title+"</h3><p class='well'>"+item.description+"</p><div class='row top-buffer'><div class='col-md-5 col-md-offset-1'><img src='img/link_icon.png' class='img-rounded' width='20px' height='20px'/><a href='www.link.com'>liNK</a></div><div class='col-md-6'><button class='btn btn-primary pull-right' id='btn'>Read More</button></a> </div></div></div>")

            });
          }
        };
    });
});
```

Can anyone notice anything wrong to this code?The format of json is proper?

Comment: if you defined `dataType :'json' `then no need of `jQuery.parseJSON(data);`

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011548/json-data-cannot-be-displayed-in-div-section-using-ajax-and-jquery#answer-38011695

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is already a object converted by jQuery. You don't need to parse.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yjsc646d/1/)

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'json.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {get_param: 'value'},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            // check with console
            console.log(data);

            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                $('#output').append("<div class='col-md-6' ><img class='img-rounded' src="+item.image+"alt='MyImage' width='550px' height='240px'></div><div class='col-md-6'><h3>"+item.title+"</h3><p class='well'>"+item.description+"</p><div class='row top-buffer'><div class='col-md-5 col-md-offset-1'><img src='img/link_icon.png' class='img-rounded' width='20px' height='20px'/><a href='www.link.com'>liNK</a></div><div class='col-md-6'><button class='btn btn-primary pull-right' id='btn'>Read More</button></a> </div></div></div>");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[LINK TO DEMO](https://fiddle.jshell.net/smsxhqgg/)

You do not have `success` in your json file so you don`t need to check

```
    if (obj.success) {
```

and you do not need the following line because data is already json

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

**js code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'json.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {get_param: 'value'},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                $('#output').append("<div class='col-md-6' ><img class='img-rounded' src=" + item.image + "alt='MyImage' width='550px' height='240px'></div><div class='col-md-6'><h3>" + item.title + "</h3><p class='well'>" + item.description + "</p><div class='row top-buffer'><div class='col-md-5 col-md-offset-1'><img src='img/link_icon.png' class='img-rounded' width='20px' height='20px'/><a href='www.link.com'>liNK</a></div><div class='col-md-6'><button class='btn btn-primary pull-right' id='btn'>Read More</button></a> </div></div></div>")

            });
        }
    });
});
```